# Regular expression to match string between { and } in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Given the following string, I tried to use regular expression match any string between just `{` and `}`, and surround it with `<tr style="display:none;"><td></td></tr>`.

I tried write the following script but it does not work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  table = ` <table border="1">
  {% Acount Summary 2018 %}
  <tbody>
    {I}
    <tr style="height: 25px;">
      <td style="padding-left: 10px;">Account Number: </td>
      {# II #}
      <td>Account</td>
      {% Active Account %}
    </tr>
    { Requested Account #}
    <tr style="height: 25px">
      <td style="padding-left: 10px;">Number of Requests: </td>
      <td>Request</td>
      {{ III }}
    </tr>
    {#
    <tr style="height: 25px">
      <td style="padding-left: 10px;">Customer: </td>
      <td>Contract Customer</td>
    </tr>
    #}
    <tr style="height: 25px">
      <td style="padding-left: 10px;"> Customoer ID</td>
      <td>ID</td>
    </tr>
    {# CustomerName #}
  </tbody>
  {# Account #}
  {{ Inactive }}
</table>
      `;
  table.replace(/({\s*?.*?.*})/g, '<tr style="display:none;"><td>$1</td></tr>');
  console.log(table);
  $('#COA').html(table);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="COA"></div>
```

What was missing? How could I correct script above to achieve above result? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reassign your variable `table`:

```
table = table.replace( ... )
```

I edited your RegEx for it to be simpler and exclude the `{}` : `{([^}]*)}`

Note that your method won't handle the nested `{}`. You would have to go the recursive road for it to do so.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  table = ` <table border="1">
  {% Acount Summary 2018 %}
  <tbody>
    {I}
    <tr style="height: 25px;">
      <td style="padding-left: 10px;">Account Number: </td>
      {# II #}
      <td>Account</td>
      {% Active Account %}
    </tr>
    { Requested Account #}
    <tr style="height: 25px">
      <td style="padding-left: 10px;">Number of Requests: </td>
      <td>Request</td>
      {{ III }}
    </tr>
    {#
    <tr style="height: 25px">
      <td style="padding-left: 10px;">Customer: </td>
      <td>Contract Customer</td>
    </tr>
    #}
    <tr style="height: 25px">
      <td style="padding-left: 10px;"> Customoer ID</td>
      <td>ID</td>
    </tr>
    {# CustomerName #}
  </tbody>
  {# Account #}
  {{ Inactive }}
</table>
      `;
  table = table.replace(/{([^}]*)}/g, '<tr style="display:none;"><td>$1</td></tr>');
  console.log(table);
  $('#COA').html(table);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="COA"></div>
```